# Update workflow for selfmade module-extensions

Tags: extension-update

I'm working on the fields of my module as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911098/608042.

I added a new field and adjusted the `version` in the XML manifest.

What's the usual workflow to bring these updates into Joomla 3?

If I upload the XML to the server and check under *Extensions > Manage*, suddenly the *Version*, *Date* and *Author* cells are completely empty.

There is no option to update the module either./

When I check the form that this module defines, the new fields are missing.
Caches are disabled.

Thanks for a short walkthrough.

I know about auto-update possibility, but I just want to do the updates in my own environments, not for anybody.

Comment: Actually I just bumped the *minor* version number instead of the *revision*, and suddenly it works.

Comment: Please add this as a proper answer below and mark it as accepted when you can ;)

Comment: @Lodder I'm not able to deterministically make this work. Today I bumped the minor revision number and refreshed the cache with the same result: _version_ and _date_ are empty. Then later I tried again and suddenly it worked, even with revision number. Now I'm changing a field configuration in XML and bump the revision number – refreshing the cache will show  the right revision, but the field keeps unchanged.

Comment: Do you have `method="upgrade"` in the top of your XML file? So it should look like this: `<extension type="module" version="3.5" client="site" method="upgrade">`

Comment: @lodder Yap I do

Comment: Just fyi, if you're willing to list your extension on JED, starting on January 10th 2017, all extensions listed on the JED will soon be required to use the [Joomla Update System](https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_Update_System). [Source](https://extensions.joomla.org/support/knowledgebase/item/joomla-update-system-requirement)